# Rspec Test expected: "/sizes" got: "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rspec Test im trying to run. It did the test manually and once you click Create Size it definitely goes to sizes_path. Why is it going to root url?

Error is

```
Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)

       expected: "/sizes"
            got: "/"

       (compared using eql?)
```

Test is

```
require "rails_helper"
require "when_authenticated.rb"
RSpec.feature "adding size" do

    let(:size01) { FactoryGirl.build :size01 }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user }
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true, password: "Password18") }

    scenario "allow a admin user to add a size" do
    admin_logged_in
        visit new_size_path
        fill_in 'Title', with: 'example'
        click_button 'Create Size'
        expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)
        expect(page).to have_content("example")
        expect(page).to have_content("You have created a new size")
    end


    scenario "user can't add size" do
        user_logged_in
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

    scenario "vistor can't add size" do
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

end
```

Here is my Create Method in Sizes controller

```
  def create
    @size = Size.new(size_params)
    if @size.save
      redirect_to sizes_path
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new size"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

New View

```
<center><h1>Create A New Size</h1></center>

<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @size do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :title %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create Size", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know you said "it definitely goes to sizes_path".  But try rearranging your expects so you check the content first, to make sure you are on that page during the test run.  If the content is wrong also, then you probably have something setup incorrectly for the test run.  In your test, you can `puts page.body` to find out what really got loaded.  Or use byebug and put a breakpoint there and poke around.

Comment: @Daiku Yeah it definitely went to the route. I did what you said before. It showed the content of the root page...

Comment: Lets see the view for new and/or the partial that has the button.

Comment: @Daiku Hello. I just added it. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I can't see the problem.  Put a breakpoint or a `puts` in the create action in the controller, and make sure that's where the button takes you.  You could also run `rake routes` and look for something odd there.  You could post your routes.rb file for us.

Comment: @Daiku I found out what the problem was admin_logged_in wasn't defined properly.

Comment: hi @joeyk16 could you pls tell me how to get the current browser window size and compare it with the expected size using the rspec?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the way my admin

Here is the fix in total

```
require "rails_helper"
# require "when_authenticated.rb"
RSpec.feature "adding size" do

    let(:size01) { FactoryGirl.build :size01 }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build :user }
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true, password: "Password18" ) }

    def admin_logged_in
      visit login_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: admin.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: admin.password
      click_button 'Log In'
    end

     def user_logged_in
      visit login_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
      click_button 'Log In'
    end

    scenario "allow a admin user to add a size" do
    admin_logged_in
        visit new_size_path
        fill_in 'Title', with: 'example'
        click_button('Create Size')
        expect(current_path).to eql(sizes_path)
        expect(page).to have_content("List Of Sizes")
        expect(page).to have_content("You have created a new size")
    end

    scenario "user can't add size" do
        user_logged_in
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

    scenario "vistor can't add size" do
        visit sizes_path    
        expect(current_path).to eql(root_path)
    end

end
```